# react-router any number of paths params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create route that can handle urls like

/results/create-order/OFR44159995010000/

and

/results/create-order/OFR44159995010000/OFR44159995010001/

and

/results/create-order/OFR44159995010000/OFR44159995010001/OFR44159995010002
and so on, and i can't figure out how i can do this. 
my Route component looks like so for now:

```
            <Route
                path="/results/create-order/:flightId(OFR\d+)"
                render={props => {
                    console.log(props);

                    return <div>here</div>;
                }}
            />
```

Comment: you want to create your order based on flightIds right ???

Comment: @PrakashKarena yes, but there can be multiple flights ids, 1 or 2 or even 10

Comment: i think you need to use array of your id's instead of route slug.

Comment: hay get my point ???

Comment: @PrakashKarena did you mean i need to parse url manually like `params.split('/')` ? Yes I think i get it. Thanks. I just think react-router has mechanism to do so out of the box

Comment: i'll explain you.wait a min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing your flight id in your route you can pass it as array to your component.

1. Create a simple route and pass your component to it

   ```
   <Route
     path="/results/create-order)"
     render={YourComponent}
   />
   ```
2. Then you can pass your flight ids as an array to your component

   ```
   <Link to={{
      pathname: '/results/create-order',
      state: { flightIds : [ pass your flight ids here ] }
   }}> My Link </Link>
   ```
3. Access your ids in your component using: `this.props.location.state.flightIds`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Route
            path="/results/create-order/:flightId"
            component={YourComponent}
        />
```

You just need to write like that and in your components, you will get flightId then write your business logic

Comment: but it works only with single :flightId, but i need that my component can get all fligh ids from url like /create-order/:flightId/:flightId
there is can be multiple flight ids

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `(OFR\d+)` in your path. `flightId` will contain whatever `id` is passed. And you can access it using `props.match.params.flightId`. The same goes for other Id's (`/:flightId/:anotherFlightId`), you just need to use different names for the Ids.

```
            <Route
                exact
                path="/results/create-order/:flightId"
                render={props => {
                    console.log(props.match.params.flightId); //logs flightId

                    return <div>here</div>;
                }}
            />
             <Route
                exact
                path="/results/create-order/:flightId/:anotherFlightId"
                render={props => {
                    console.log(props.match.params.anotherFlightId); //logs anotherFlightId

                    return <div>here</div>;
                }}
            />
```

Comment: but here can be 20 flights ids

Comment: Whoa! So you need a generic Route that handles them all? @ЕвгенийЛитвиненко